# Active contour snake

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision, image-segmentation, contour

I am trying using MATLAB activecontour code to segment the region. the example was used grayscale image while i am using binary image. it turn out ok when i run the code by calling the binary image. however, when i combined the code, nothing happen. it skips the iteration part, and generate the sama binary image. for your reference, below is my code.

```
%% snake 
figure
x = imread('1.jpg');
threshold = 160;
I = rgb2gray(x);
I = Igray>threshold;
imshow (I);

I = imresize(I,.5); 
imshow(I)
title('Original Image')

mask = zeros(size(I));
mask(25:end-25,25:end-25) = 1;
imshow(mask)
title('Initial Contour Location')
bw = activecontour(I,mask,1300);
imshow(bw)
title('Segmented Image, 300 Iterations')
```

no process happen starting from snake's code. it eventually only generate binary image. I hope someone could try run this and help me to find my mistake. Thank you in advance

Comment: Why are you running a snake on a binary image? why throw away the information from the gray-scale image and make its work more difficult?

Comment: At first I tried active region based technique.I hv tried by using using grayscale image however, the segmentation was not really nice so i decided to try the technique by using binary image. the binary image obtained will be fused together with RGB image as final image. the reason why i changed to binary is to obtained the wanted region because grayscale has some unnecessary things and it couldnt segment the region i wanted. I used snake for comparison with active region based actually. and to make it fair,I changed it to binary image. unfortunately, it doesnt work when I combined the code.

Comment: Looking at the docs for the function you’re using, it seems you are using Chan-Vese active contours. This is a level set method, not a snake. It’s a completely different algorithm.

Comment: Please post your input image, so we can reproduce your results. Can’t know what the problem is if we don’t see what is going on.

Comment: https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/activecontour.html- i copied the code from this website. which is stated snake. or actually I misunderstood here?

Comment: https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/19567-active-contour-segmentation---- and this is another method that i tried.

Comment: Yes, I  noticed that the MATLAB documentation is confused about what snakes are. I already filed a report, hopefully they will fix that. Snakes are the original active contours. When level-set methods were introduced to image processing, they more or less took over and made snakes obsolete. Still, snakes are very easy to implement and still are useful for some purposes.

Comment: so actually the code is chan vese method? and the second link I sent is upgraded chan vese isnt it?

Comment: I don’t know, it just says it implements Chan-Vese from the original paper.

Comment: the code from MATLAB documentation is chan vese right? However, do you know why the code from MATLAB documentation unable to segment the binary image (as shown in my very first question) if i combined the code

Comment: Btw Sir Cris Luengo, thank you so much for your help. I appreciated it a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Matlab's `activecontour` function uses the Chan–Vese ([active contours without edges](https://doi.org/10.1109/83.902291)) method by default, like Cris said. The implementation "uses the Sparse-Field level-set method, similar to the method described in [3]", citing [Whitaker, "A level-set approach to 3d reconstruction from range data"](https://doi.org/10.1023/A:1008036829907). (Besides Chan–Vese, `activecontour` has an optional `method` arg that can be set to 'edge' to use an alternative "edge-based model" based on the (older) [geodesic active contours](https://doi.org/10.1023/A:1007979827043) method of Caselles, Kimmel, and Sapiro.)

The Chan–Vese method segments a grayscale image by looking for a binary image equal to "c1" inside the contour and "c2" outside the contour that both has a smooth contour and is a good approximation to the original image. The method optimizes c1, c2, and the shape of the contour, beginning from some initial contour and evolving it by an iterative process.

If you'll excuse a self-citation, you can find an article, open source C code, and online demo about Chan–Vese on the IPOL journal at http://www.ipol.im/pub/art/2012/g-cv/, which you may find helpful.

So why is it not working in your case? Some thoughts:

- In your use, since the input image is *already* binary, it is clearly tempting for the method to simply set c1=0, c2=1, and the contour to the edges of the input, so "nothing happens". Try setting the optional 'SmoothFactor' arg (possibly to a large value) to force the method to look for a smoother contour.
- It's conceivably a datatype problem, since image `I` is passed as a logical array to `activecontour`, but normally the function takes a numeric array. Try casting `I` to a double array before passing.

Comment: hi Sir, thank you for your answer. definitely will try to cast I to double. however, may you help me to find the real snake coding?  I need the original active contour coding as chan vese method, as far as I know, is the updated version of active contour right?. please correct me if Im wrong. I am still new to this, and it is quite hard for me to understand the fundamental of chan vese method itself but thank you for you answer, I got new info today (:

Comment: sorry Sir, I mean maybe you could suggest me to find the original snake code. maybe some sources that I could refer to. Anyway, I have tried your suggestion and it worked. Thank you so much.

Comment: "Snakes" are a family of methods, it is more than one approach. You can find a few implementations on Matlab Central File Exchange, like ["Snake : Active Contour"](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/28149-snake-active-contour). There's a Python implementation of [snakes in scikit-image](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/segmentation/plot_morphsnakes.html). Or if you want to implement it yourself, the [snakes pseudocode on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_contour_model#Implementation) would be a good starting point.

Comment: Alright sir, I will give it a try. Thank you so much for your help.